# What are these distortions when plotting fill_between in polar coordinates? And how do I get rid of them?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, polar-coordinates, spiral

I want to plot a spiral with varying width. When I plot the figure, however, there are peculiar dots that appear above and below the line (where the red arrows are pointing in the image below). They seem to be occurring between points, where the line should just be straight. They do not occur in any obvious pattern either.

[image: Distortions where red arrows point]

I have run the following code, but I can't figure out what is causing these weird distortions. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.use('Agg')
plt.ioff()

MY_DPI = 300
BKGD_COLOUR = 'w'
FILL_COLOUR= 'k'

a = 0
b = 0.5

maxRadius = 100
maxTheta = (maxRadius - a) / b

t = np.arange(0, maxTheta, 0.1)
r = a + b *t

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=MY_DPI)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], polar=True)
ax.set_rlim(0, maxRadius)
ax.axis('off')

r_bot = np.array(r) - np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, len(r))
r_top = np.array(r) + np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, len(r))

ax.fill_between(t, r_bot, r_top, color=FILL_COLOUR, lw=0)

plt.savefig('spiraliser.jpg', facecolor=BKGD_COLOUR, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=MY_DPI)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Looks like a jpg compression artifact.  Try using png and see if it persists.

Comment: @James I tried saving as png, but the problem persists. thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `color=FILL_COLOUR` to `facecolor=FILL_COLOUR` seems to have solved this issue. Apparently `facecolor` does not set the colour of the edge.